# How can I make my application route properly in Flask?

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

Using Flask and SQLAlchemy, I have two models:

`ToDoList` - parent of `Todo`

`Todo` - child of `ToDoList`

I have created a controller to take a checkbox input from `ToDoList` that also updates all of its `Todo` child records. That works well and checks out when I query the database.

The problem I'm having is that when I click the `Todolist` checkbox I want the view to immediately update both the todo list and its associated todos, which are displayed alongside each other. This doesn't happen. It only updates when I hit reload.

Here's my controller code:

```
@app.route('/lists/<list_id>/set-completed', methods=['POST'])
def set_completed_list(list_id):
    try:
        completed = request.get_json()['completed']
        todo_list = ToDoList.query.get(list_id)
        todo_list.completed = completed
        db.session.query(Todo).filter_by(list_id=list_id).update({"completed": completed}, synchronize_session='fetch')
        db.session.commit()
    except:
        db.session.rollback()
    finally:
        db.session.close()
        return redirect(url_for('get_list_todos', list_id=list_id))

@app.route('/lists/<list_id>')
def get_list_todos(list_id):
    return render_template('index.html', active_list=ToDoList.query.get(list_id), lists=ToDoList.query.all(), todos=Todo.query.filter_by(list_id=list_id).order_by('id').all())
```

My view won't update, even if I send a fixed `list_id` to `get_list_todos`. It's like it's just ignoring the redirect altogether. I know the template rendering works OK because everything refreshes fine when I reload the initial `index` page with no parameters:

```
@app.route('/')
def index():
    return redirect(url_for('get_list_todos', list_id=1))
```

I'm still learning Flask. Can anyone see any obvious mistakes that I'm missing?

Comment: I don't think it's due to a bug in your code within your route. It seems to me that you have a problem understanding the behavior of an ajax request. How do you use the server's answer within your request? The redirect function sends by default an http status code 302 (Found) and a location header that contains the url. In the case of a regular call, the browser would now call up the specified address independently. With an ajax request you have to take care of it yourself.

Comment: Thanks @Detlef. As you say, I misunderstood how views and controllers interact with Ajax calls. I will answer the question so that other noobs can see the result. Thanks again for clarifying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I still have a lot to learn about Ajax. I didn't understand how controllers and views interact on Ajax calls. I assumed the controller could direct the browser where it needed to go, but what I really needed to do was let the know the browser that the operation had been successful using a response and then let Javascript reload the page on the view side:

Controller:

```
@app.route('/lists/<list_id>/set-completed', methods=['POST'])
def set_completed_list(list_id):
    error = False
    try:
        completed = request.get_json()['completed']
        todo_list = ToDoList.query.get(list_id)
        todo_list.completed = completed
        db.session.query(Todo).filter_by(list_id=list_id).update({"completed": completed}, synchronize_session='fetch')
        db.session.commit()
    except:
        db.session.rollback()
        error = True
    finally:
        db.session.close()
    if error:
        abort(500)
    else:
        return jsonify({'success': True})
```

Client-side Javascript:

```
   const list_checkboxes = document.querySelectorAll('.list-check-completed');
    for (let i = 0; i < list_checkboxes.length; i++) {
      const list_checkbox = list_checkboxes[i];
      list_checkbox.onchange = function (e) {
        console.log('event', e);
        const list_newCompleted = e.target.checked;
        const listId = e.target.dataset['id'];
        fetch('/lists/' + listId + '/set-completed', {
          method: 'POST',
          body: JSON.stringify({
            'completed': list_newCompleted,
          }),
          headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          }
        })
          .then(response => response.json())
          .then(jsonResponse => {
          console.log('response', jsonResponse);
          window.location.reload(true);
          document.getElementById('error').className = 'hidden';
        })
          .catch(function () {
            document.getElementById('error').className = '';
          })
      }
    }
```

The `window.location.reload(true)` takes care of the reload.